# photoshop javascript open atn file

Tags: javascript, regex, decode, photoshop

i have a really annoyong problem.

```
var Scriptfile = new File($.fileName);  
var basePath = Scriptfile.path; 
var topFolder = new Folder(basePath+"/actions");
var fileandfolderAr = scanSubFolders(topFolder,/\.(atn)$/i);
var fileList = fileandfolderAr[0];

for (var a = 0 ;a < fileList.length; a++) {
  var atnFile = new File(fileList[a]);
  alert(atnFile.name);
  var rex = new RegExp (decodeURI(atnFile.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '')), "g");
  if (!atnFile.exists) {
    alert("Your ActionSet does not exist!\nPlease contact your administrator.");
    return false;
  }
  var actionList = getActionSets();
  //if ActionSet Exists remove it.
  var flag = 0;
  for (var d in actionList) {
    if (decodeURI(actionList[d]).match(rex)) {
      flag = 1; 
      continue;
    }    
  }
  if (!atnFile.exists) {
    alert("File does not exist");
    return false;
  }
  if (flag == 0) {
    app.load(atnFile);
  }
}
```

This piece of code is working very well if the atn file isn't placed in a folder or subfolder which contains a white space in it's name.

If i have a folder name like "photoshop script" it won't load my atn file.

Any ideas?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that nobody knows how to solve this, you big programmers. I found the solution. All i have to do is to decode the path to the file. I just replaced the `var atnFile = new File(fileList[a]);` with    `var atnFile= new File(decodeURI(fileList[a]));` . I hope this will help someone sometime.